# Scanner useLocale Resource leak

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, spring-tool-suite, resource-leak

Hello my fellow programmers.

I have some code which the spring tool suite editor responds differently too, maybe some of you smart people know why.

```
File inputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Input.txt");
    Scanner sc = null;
    double payment=0;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(inputFile).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        //sc = new Scanner(inputFile)
        //sc.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        payment = sc.nextDouble();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me why this is not possible:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

but this is!?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
sc.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

the first line up code gives me a warning "Resource leak: unassigned closeable value is never closed", and as you can see i've in my try/catch used a finally which should always close my object if it's not null.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the compiler warning you about something it doesn't (or rather can't) understand.

When `useLocale()` is called, the same `Scanner` instance it was called on is returned. However the compiler can't know that and issues a warning. If the method returned a different `Scanner` object, the resource leak would be valid as the original `Scanner` object would have disappeared without being closed.

An unwarranted warning, that you may ignore.

Comment: Okay thank you for the quick response Kayaman. Both statements work, but i'll go with the one not creating a warning.

and thank you for the extra input Stephen

Comment: Ah you're right indeed, an exception would create a resource leak. I'm a bit surprised that `Scanner` even provides a fluent builder pattern like that.

Answer (score 1):

Kayaman has identified one problem.  Another is that the `useLocale()` call could (in theory<sup>1</sup>) throw an exception. If that happened, `sc` would not be assigned ... and the `Scanner` would not be closed. That is a warranted warning!

Either way, the correct way to write this code is as follows:

```
File inputFile = new File(....);
double payment = 0;
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile)) {
    sc.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    payment = sc.nextDouble();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do something about it
}
```

Note that the *try-with-resources* takes care of the closing, and I do NOT catch and squash `java.lang.Exception`.  (Catching `Exception` is bad.  Squashing it is even worse.)

And this version is fewer lines of code.  More concise *and* more correct == big win!

---

<sup>1 - I looked at the source code, and I can see ways that you could get an NPE or an OOME in a `useLocale()` call.</sup>

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but everytime I see a try-with-resource example I feel like I have less options for debugging, but maybe you have some input too that as well? like the same goes of course with the object and method on the same line. Couldn't you say that the most 'correct' way of writing code would always be multiple lines for readablity (offtopic I know but would like your opinion since you code it like that)

Comment: I don't see how there are less options.  You can still set breakpoints in all of the places that matter.  In fact, since the try-with-resources takes care of closing in a bomb-proof manner, there are liable to be fewer storage leaks and other bugs; e.g. NPE's because you forgot the null check.

Comment: Alright, I will take that into consideration in future developing. Thank you for the responses.